# Background image on body is partially hidden by container-fluid class

Tags: html, css

I have used a background image on body to cover full screen but it is partially hidden by container-fluid class from bootstrap3.

```
    body
    {
       background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center
    }
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? jsfiddle.net

Comment: Have you tried setting the backgrounds of overlapping containers to transparent?

Comment: yes, i have tried adding <--! .container-fluid{
    background-color: transparent;
} --> but it does not work.

Comment: In the fiddle i am unable to give a background image , and the problem is specifically occurring with background image and not with background-color. when i remove the above code for background image and replace it with <--! background-color:aqua; --> the page shows just fine.